# Excel Countif Formula I'm trying to copy the formula down

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to copy the formula in `G3` down to all the cells but when I do it looks at the cells in the formula and keeps them.If I wanted to keep the cells typically I would use `$K$3` but I want the opposite in this case.  I want to be able to copy because I have around 2500 lines of data.

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"M3","P3","S3"}),">0"))
```

Comment: can you be a little more elaborate? screenshots of input and desired output?

Comment: Why do you need to use `INDIRECT()`?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an Excel-VBA question. If it is, please post your code, if it isn't, please remove the tag.

Comment: @SteveES, I agree - tag removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
=SUM(M3>0,P3>0,S3>0)
```